# Laravel Eloquent how to use between operator

Tags: php, sql, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I am trying to find an elegant way in Eloquent and Laravel to say

```
select * from UserTable where Age between X and Y
```

Is there a between operator in Eloquent (I can't find it).

The closest i have gotten so far is chainging my query like this

```
$query->where(age, '>=', $ageFrom)
      ->where(age, '<=', $ageTo);
```

I also came across whereRaw that seems to work

```
$query->whereRaw('age BETWEEN ' . $ageFrom . ' AND ' . $ageTo . '');
```

Is there an actual Eloquent way (not raw) that deals with ranges?

Answer (score 152, accepted):

```
$query->whereBetween('age', [$ageFrom, $ageTo]);
```

Still holds true for Laravel 10+ https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/queries#additional-where-clauses

Comment: Thank you! I will look over the selects carefully :)

Comment: What could be the equivalent using eloquent to:

select * from UserTable where X between column1 and column2

Comment: @Brian i think you would have to use `whereRaw()`, in case X is a binding value. If X is a column name, then you could use `->whereColumn('X', '<=', 'column1')->where('X', '=>', 'column2')`, which could also be written in a single `whereColumn([['X', '<=', 'column1'], ['X', '=>', 'column2']])`

Answer (score 7):

The `whereBetween` method verifies that a column's value is between two values:

```
$users = DB::table('users')->whereBetween('votes', [1, 100])->get();
```

The `whereNotBetween` method verifies that a column's value lies outside of two values:

```
$users = DB::table('users')->whereNotBetween('votes', [1, 100])->get();
```

[Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries#additional-where-clauses)