# How to implement this query in laravel?

Tags: mysql, laravel

```
select *
from tr_sewaiklan
where '2018-12-09' BETWEEN tgl_mulai AND tgl_selesai
```

Comment: You should add code of your model and the code of what you have tried so far.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26746918/laravel-eloquent-how-to-use-between-operator

Comment: nope dude, because whereBetween format is field_date and then array value, but in my query format is value_date and then field_date...

Answer (score 1):

```
DB::tabe('tr_swaiklan')->where('2018-12-09', '>', $tgl_mulai)->where('2018-12-09', '<', $tgl_selesai)->get();
```

the `<>` Operator might be used too

it's quite well described in the official documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries#where-clauses

Comment: thanks for help but your query doesnt work.. but finally i use raw expression

Answer (score 1):

See [Laravel Eloquent how to use between operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26746918/laravel-eloquent-how-to-use-between-operator)

to test in tinker without model, try

`\DB::table('table')->whereBetween('date_field', ['2018-12-09', '2019-01-01'])->get();`

---

from comment

```
DB::table('tr_sewaiklan')->where(function ($query) {
    $query
        ->where('tgl_mulai', '<', '2018-12-09')
        ->where('tgl_selesai', '>', '2018-12-09');
});
```

Comment: nope dude, because whereBetween format is field_date and then array value, but in my query format is value_date and then field_date...

Comment: Sorry, misread your question, my bad. If you want an alternative to raw queries you could use a where closure, something like

    DB::table('tr_sewaiklan')->where(function ($query) {
        $query
            ->where('tgl_mulai', '<', '2018-12-09')
            ->where('tgl_selesai', '>', '2018-12-09');
    });
If your date is really a variable you `use ()` it in the closure

Answer (score 0):

Finally i solved my problem with raw expression not with eloquent because whereBetween format is field_date and then value_date but in my case my query format is value_date and then field_date.

thanks for your help guys..

```
DB::select(DB::raw("SELECT a.* FROM tr_sewaiklan a LEFT JOIN tb_iklanposisi b ON a.id_posisi=b.id WHERE '".date('Y-m-d')."' BETWEEN tgl_mulai AND tgl_selesai"));
```

Comment: `date('Y-m-d')` - Why not just use [CURDATE()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_curdate)?